# Как написать функции для DataFrame, которая будет заполнять пропуски в столбцах, при этом используя данные других столбцов? Python, pandas

Tags: python, pandas, машинное-обучение, kaggle, etl

Пытался написать функцию для обработки датасета (для последующего использования в машинном обучении).

В процессе подготовки данных столкнулся с тем, что по некоторым важным параметрам отсутствует большое количество данных (до 57%), эти столбцы конечно можно откинуть, но тогда точность предсказания модели упадет.

Поэтому пропуски лучше заполнить и использовать эти столбцы. Тут возникает следующая проблема: средним значением их заполнять нет смысла, т.к. это опять-таки ухудшит точность (интерполяция тоже не подойдет).

Поэтому решил написать функцию, которая на входе будет принимать список столбцов с пропусками, список вспомогательных столбцов и DataFrame, который необходимо избавить от пропусков в указанных столбцах.
Затем для каждой строки с пропуском функция будет собирать таблицу из отфильтрованных строк начального DataFrame, таким образом, чтоб значения каждой строки по вспомогательным столбцам совпадали со значениями в этих же столбцах в строке с пропуском.
Далее высчитывалось бы среднее значение в отфильтрованной таблице и вставлялось на место пропуска в начальный DataFrame.

Этот способ заполнил бы пропуски таким образом, что сохранилась бы зависимость между столбцами и точность модели не снизилась бы (теоретически).

Вот код функции, который я написал, правда он выдает ошибку, да и я что-то напутал в коде похоже:

```
def na_filler_num(cols_na_num, cols_help, train_all, train):
    for col in cols_na_num:
        help_table = train.copy()
        help_table = help_table[help_table[col] == help_table[col]] # таблица в которой нет пропусков в нужном столбце
        for row in range(0, len(train_all)-1):
            help_table_row = help_table.copy() # вспомогательная таблица, в которой будут отфильтровываться все строки с одинаковыми категориями в столбцах из cols_help, таблица обновляется для каждой строки
            if train_all[col].iloc()[row] != train_all[col].iloc()[row]: # проверяет-есть ли пропуск в строке по столбцу col
                for column in cols_help: # проходит по всем столбцам из cols_help и отбрасывает все строки с другими значениями из этих столбцов
                    help_table_row = help_table_row[help_table_row[column] == train_all[column].iloc()[row]].copy() # с каждым циклом отфильтровывает таблицу по одному столбцу из cols_help, в итоге после финального цикла,
                    # в таблице остаются только те строки, которые совпадают по своим категориальным значениям со строкой, в которой есть пропуск.
                return help_table_row[col].mean()
            else:
                return train_all[col].iloc()[row]
```

Также не совсем понял, как правильно будет использовать эту функцию, использовать ее  с `.apply()` или лучше чтобы функция вызывалась отдельно и сама меняла DataFrame. Вот ошибка, которую я получил: [image: Вывод ошибки при запуске]

Comment: Ваша функция явно предназначена для простого вызова, а не для `apply`. Функция для `apply` будет иметь только один аргумент - например `row` таблицы, к которой она применяется.

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: А вообще, если я правильно понял, вы лучше тогда постройте модель для заполнения пропусков. Например, линейную регрессию, и тогда вам не нужно будет ничего усреднять. Тренируете модель на предсказание нужного столбца в том датафрейме, где нет пропусков - и применяете к этому датафрейму с пропусками. Думаю, так гораздо проще будет и правильнее.

Comment: @CrazyElf спасибо, я что-то даже не подумал про такой вариант. Попробую его)

Comment: @Step1709 Всё придумано до нас )  Стратегий заполнения пропусков вообще много разных  https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html  Кстати, не факт, что они вам помогут улучшить скор. Для применения сложных моделей типа бустингов может быть лучше даже и не заполнять пропуски. Но это вам нужно самому проверять, сравнивать разные варианты.

Comment: @CrazyElf, еще раз спасибо-посмотрю инфу. Кстати еще одно решение пришло на ум, не знаю верное или нет, но возможно можно было попробовать мультииндекс если я правильно понял, как он работают)